# How spark sql queries turn into a number of stages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple spark-submit job which:

- Reads a CSV file
- Performs an SQL aggregate and ordering
- shows the aggregate
- Stores the result to parquet

I have kept shuffle partitions to 4 and can see a total of 7 stages being created (4 for saving the parquet, 2 for show action and 1 for I guess reading the file, not sure).

I have couple of questions **here**:

1. Why parquet storage has 4 stages, not more than or less than that and similar thing with other stages from show?
2. Why does Spark SQL queries start stages in the background?

[image: Stages]

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",4)
df = spark.read.csv('/raj/data/test.csv', header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("visitors")
sqldf=spark.sql("select NAMELAST,NAMEFIRST,NAMEMID,count(*) as frequency  from visitors group by NAMELAST,NAMEFIRST,NAMEMID  order by count(*) desc ")
sqldf.show()
sqldf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/tmp/data/key=1")
```

Comment: I didn't get you? @thebluephantom

Comment: What was the master config? Just on a linux vm or cluster? I assume small environment

Comment: Yes a machine with 16gb ram and 4 cores and spark running on master,slave standalone architecture in dockers @thebluephantom

Comment: ok, clear, but you submited to spark standalone?

Comment: actually does not matter

Comment: yes @thebluephantom it doesn't matter how you submit

Comment: not sure we understand eachother but I am on holidays starting my 32gb 4 core linux laptop juts to refresh!

Comment: i will answer tomorrow

Comment: @thebluephantom did you get any answer for it?

Comment: yes i did. i had to review myself again. i am writing my own noes and will post in due course. what is your real concern?

Comment: @thebluephantom I have put it in two points in my questions, why and how parts in question

Comment: Well the how do you not mean why for example?

Comment: long story will post tomorrow

Comment: I have accepted the answer in case you want to still improve your answer please do that @thebluephantom

Comment: Well i upvoted you and you really need to run it and look at it yourself. Its a lot of explaining for 15 pts. Its all shuffling exchanging and knowing that show is a special case api. I think i did alright and it is correct.

Comment: yes, it is correct so I upvoted it @thebluephantom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In General**

- Reading the generated output from Spark UI etc. is not an easy task imho. I am used to explains from ORACLE etc. (Not quite the same though as DAG visualization, however.)
- Using DFs is different to RDDs; a lot of the stuff on Stages on the web relates to that time, but Catalyst and DFs work a little different and it is oft stated do not worry about that.
- It is sometimes stated that `show` can fumble up the Catalyst Optimizer. Not sure if that really is the case.
- Per release the DAG visualization changes and may be there are bugs. I checked the former point.
- *Exchange / Shuffling is the clue!*
- Each API does its own thing.

**Your Questions Generally**

First up, you have 2 Actions:

- `show`... show
- `write.`. parquet
- You need to look more at the associated SQL and the Details to get the picture. Otherwise - imho - it's hard to follow.
- Since there is no caching, both start from the beginning of the flow both times, but there is a skipped stage. Adding `sqldf.cache()` is a recommendation.

**Stage 0**

- Stage 0 is common for both Actions. It is simply read the *header*. Adding *inferSchema* will add another Stage.

**show**

- There is a `read` and a `count` `within partition per grouping` (like Hadoop Combiner) (Stage).
- Then there is an `overall groupBy / count` (Stage).
- The `show` is a `take ordered` which does not require a shuffle / exchange in any way. `show` is a *specific implementation* that is not used in production jobs (No exchange so no new Stage) that has its own internal implementation.

**write**

Note there is a skipped stage

- There is a `read` and a `count within partition per grouping` (like Hadoop Combiner) (Stage).
- Then there is an `overall groupBy / count` (Stage).
- The there a `sort`(Stage) require a shuffle / exchange from previous.
- The `write` then is a (separate Stage) that gets the shuffled down to 2 partitions output. The sort reduces the partitions (from 4 to 2).

**Final comments**
Not intuitive, need a bit of feeling.